# 2 fragment transactions not possible in onCreate()

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, oncreate, fragmenttransaction

I tried to perform 2 fragment transactions in `onCreate()`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    bottomNav_main.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    val firstFragment = OpeningFragment()
    firstFragment.arguments = intent.extras
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, firstFragment, "add_activitymain")
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, OptionsFragment(), "add_options")
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, LeaderboardsFragment(), "add_leaderboards")
    transaction.commit()

    val transaction2 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val options: Fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("add_options")!!
    val leaderboards: Fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("add_leaderboards")!!
    transaction2.hide(options)
    transaction2.hide(leaderboards)
    transaction2.commit()
}
```

however received a NullPointerException on `options` variable. But when I seperate the 2nd transaction into the `onStart()` method, it works fine:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    bottomNav_main.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    val firstFragment = OpeningFragment()
    firstFragment.arguments = intent.extras
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, firstFragment, "add_activitymain")
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, OptionsFragment(), "add_options")
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, LeaderboardsFragment(), "add_leaderboards")
    transaction.commit()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val transaction2 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val options: Fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("add_options")!!
    val leaderboards: Fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("add_leaderboards")!!
    transaction2.hide(options)
    transaction2.hide(leaderboards)
    transaction2.commit()
}
```

Can somebody explain why this is?

Answer (score 0):

That is mostly because commiting a transaction doesn't happen instantly. It takes a few seconds and works asynchronous. Try commitNow() to make it instant and synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

> **Fragment transition not possible in onCreate()**

Try doing it in **onViewCreated()**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
    create()
}
```